# Use localstorage to store user/password pairs

Tags: html, authentication, local-storage

So, I'm working with localstorage and need to create a login page. That will only login with those users that register in that same browser/mobile phone were the registe was done. The problem that I'm facing is that, I can only have on pair user/password because I dont know how to check it. I'll explain: if I have more that one user, it would login with any user/pass as long they where in the localStorge, and not necessarily with the corresponding ones. I need to check if the user is the "owner" of that password.

Comment: Do you really have a client side only authentication? Sounds like something very easy to work around..

Comment: Yes, no php, no server side. I already searched and cant get what I need. How can I make it to recognize if it is, or not, a log in pair ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to serialize an array to localStorage.

```
// to store some logins:
var logins=[];

logins[0]={username: someusername, password: somepassword };

logins[1]={username: someotherusername, password: someotherpassword };

localStorage['logins']=JSON.stringify(logins);

// to fetch all:
var storedLogins=JSON.parse(localStorage['logins']);
```

Comment: How do I send the new user/pass to the array, when the user complete the register ?